# calling an object with inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

First things first, I'm reasonably new to python, but I have been working hard and doing lots of tutorials and sample projects to get better, so, if I'm missing something obvious, I appologize.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, and I've done a number of searches here and through the googles, but I can't quite figure out how to turn the examples I've found into what I'm looking for, so I was hoping someone here could give me a push in the right direction.

```
class Super1:
    def __init__(self,artib1,atrib2,atrib3):
        self.atrib1 = atrib1
        self.atrib2 = atrib2
        self.atrib3 = atrib3

class Sub1(Super1):
    def __init__(self,atrib4,atrib5,atrib6)
        self.atrib4 = atrib4
        self.atrib5 = atrib5
        self.atrib6 = atrib6
```

okay, so what I'm having trouble figuring out is, in the tutroials I've done, they said that I could call on the class like this:

```
spam = Super1("eggs","foo","bar")
```

and if I input

```
print spam.atrib1
```

it would spit out

```
eggs
```

What I want to do is make spam = Sub1, but I don't know how to call it so that I can set all the 'attrib's the way I did with Super1.

I looked up a number of 'multiple inheritance' examples, but I can't seem to reconcile the examples into my own needs. Most of the tutorials don't have more than 1 atribute, or often have the sub 'override' the atributes of the super.

I also checked into composition, and I'm not sure that's exactly what I'm looking for for this part of my project, but I do know that I will need it in later parts.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: You're not calling the superclass constructor, and you're not taking the arguments needed for that constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to call the parent class's constructor `Super1.__init__(self)`
2. You also need to allow `Sub1` to take the arguments for the parent class's constructor.

With the modifications above, your code becomes:

```
class Sub1(Super1):
    def __init__(self, artib1, atrib2, atrib3, atrib4, atrib5, atrib6)
        Super1.__init__(self, artib1, atrib2, atrib3)
        self.atrib4 = atrib4
        self.atrib5 = atrib5
        self.atrib6 = atrib6
```

However, rather than calling the parent class's constructor yourself, you should use the `super` built-in function:

```
super(Sub1, self).__init__(artib1, atrib2, atrib3)
```

That way, you don't have to hard-code the name of the parent class in each sub-classes constructor. This allows you to easily refactor your code. Another added benefit of using `super` is that will automatically deal with the sticky details of multiple-inheritance problems such as ["diamond inheritance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

One more piece of advice is that if you don't know the amount of positional arguments ahead of time that the super class will take, you can use the `*args` syntax:

```
class Sub1(Super1):
        def __init__(self, atrib4, atrib5, atrib6, *args)
            super(Sub1, self).__init__(*args)
            self.atrib4 = atrib4
            self.atrib5 = atrib5
            self.atrib6 = atrib6
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to help out @WardSeabrook :-) If this answer helped, [consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If `Sub1` inherits from `Super1`, that's supposed to mean it *is a* Super1 (with some extra stuff added, or with some customizations). But you can't remove things, so `Sub1` *must*

1. contain everything a `Super1` contains
2. initialize the `Super1` part of itself by calling `super(Sub1,self).1.__init__(self, ...)` in its own constructor.

So, if you your super class has a member `a`, whose value is passed to its constructor, your subclass *also* has (inherits) a member `a`, and must somehow pass its value to the superclass constructor.

Whether that means

```
class Sub1(Super1):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        super(Sub1, self).__init__(a,b,c)
        self.d=d
        self.e=e
        self.f=f
```

or whether there's some relationship between the super and subclass arguments (or the subclass hard-codes some of the superclass arguments, or ...) depends on your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `spam = Super1("eggs","foo","bar")`. It will call `Super` class constructor.

Comment: No, it will not. There *is no `Super`* class.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're suggesting here. I did call `spam = Super1("eggs","foo","bar")` what I want to do is call `spam = Sub1("eggs","foo","bar")` but also set `atrib1,atrib2,atrib3` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you want to create a instance for the `Sub1` you should `spam = Super1("eggs","foo","bar",atrib4,atrib5,atri6)`. Also you have to change the constructor for the `Sub1` as:

```
def __init__(self,atrib1,atrib2,atrib3,atrib4,atrib5,atrib6):
     Super1.__init__(self,atrib1,atrib2,atrib3)
     self.atrib4 = atrib4
     self.atrib5 = atrib5
     self.atrib6 = atrib6`
```